# hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto impact current DB

Tags: java, hibernate

Let's say my app has `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update`.  If I add a composite index directly to the DB, will the app drop the index when it starts a new SessionFactory lifecycle (from [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-hbmddl))?  I am rather new to hibernate, reading someone else's code, so sorry if this is a bad question.

Our goal:  One of the `selects` that the application does is quite inefficient because it is using 2 columns, neither of which are indexes.  But if I added a complex index for these two columns, it would be much more efficient, I expect.  This is what I would do with more normal application, at least.  Just don't want to add an index to the DB and have it get dropped randomly on reboots or something.

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: Because it is a production DB, and don’t have a dev setup right now.

Comment: If I could, I would fix the app.  But the code I have has some errors, and I have more important projects to get to, so figured this might be a quick solution until I have time to do it properly in application code.